# Using Coldfusion to write to a USB flash drive on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to write a file to a USB drive located at /media/user/drive_name

The directory I am working in is /var/www/html/site_folder

`<cffile action="write" file="../../../../media/user/drive_name/hello.txt" output="hello">`

I get "Parent directory for /media/user/drive_name/hello.txt doesn't exist"

I have tried reading the file and it tells me it is not a file.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: With Linux, you should be able to read directly from the mount point, not needing to backtrack from the current folder that contains the CF code. It's more likely that the CF Server user does not have access to mounted drives that like one.

Comment: ``` <cfdump var="#getFileInfo("/media/user")#">``` returns permission info. When I add the drive to the path it still tells me the path does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This throws an error:

```
<cffile action="write" file="../../../../media/user/drive_name/hello.txt" output="hello">
```

> Parent directory for /media/user/drive_name/hello.txt doesn't exist

But this returns permission info:

```
<cfdump var="#getFileInfo("/media/user")#">
```

Your initial code is trying to reference the `/media` folder / drive from a relative path. On Linux, you should be able to access a root / mount folder directly from the main directory.

Can the server read this file?

```
<cffile action="read" file="/media/user/drive_name/hello.txt" variable ="content">
```

Answer (score -2):

Thank you Adrian J Moreno for your reply. Yes I had tried it both relative and absolute and neither worked. What did finally work is we had to run Lucee as the root user which gave it permission.

Comment: Running as root is a major security concern. You do not want to do that on production (or really any) servers.

Comment: @Miguel-F Agreed. Paul, this goes back to my initial comment about the CF user having the correct permission to access that mounted USB drive. You should figure out how to give the CF user the correct access. If you allow your server to run as `root`, then any code on your application can now access any files on your server. A developer could accidentally delete files and folders anywhere on the server. A hacker could have full access to your server should one manage to get into your app.